# R studio carriage return using tk_choose.file issue

Tags: r

So I am using R studio (Version 1.0.143) and using tk_choose.files

```
library(tcltk)
df <- read.xlsx2(tk_choose.files(caption = "Choose File"), 
             sheetIndex = 1, 
             startRow=4,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

After selecting my file from the Windows file folder, everything works as expected.  However, every for our five seconds a newline appears in my console now.  How can I prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is even happening when I use df <- file.choose(new = FALSE), which is a base function.

Comment: It is still happening even though I have no processes running

Comment: This has something to do with loading a 32bit driver on a 64 machine.  I had to do that since I am working with MS Access that required it.

Comment: So I never figured out why choose.files() was doing that for me.  I switched and started using library(rChoiceDialogs) and that seemed to solve the issue.